# How to execute the groovy script written on the Jenkins parameters in slave node

Tags: jenkins, groovy

My small piece of code

```
def proc ='./test.py'.execute()
proc.waitFor()

def output = proc.in.text
def exitcode = proc.exitValue()
def error = proc.err.text

return output.tokenize()
```

This above groovy script will execute from one of the **Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter** in my Jenkins pipeline. Is there anyway to execute this from different slave. I don't have idea that the groovy script written in parameter will execute from other slave or not..

Could someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 pipeline {
        
        agent {
            node { label "name-of-slave-jenkins"}
        }
        
        stages {
     
            stage('stage 1') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        def proc ='./test.py'.execute()
                        proc.waitFor()
                    }
                }
            }
                
            stage('stage 2') {            
                steps{
                    script{
    
                        def output = proc.in.text
                        def exitcode = proc.exitValue()
                        def error = proc.err.text
    
                        return output.tokenize()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort @DACQ. Actually I need to run this code in "Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter". Im sorry that I have not mentioned that